# Forçar F5 na página

Tags: javascript

Meu problema: eu cadastro uma informação através de uma modal dialog, quando eu clico em salvar, essa informação não lista automaticamente na listagem no IE, mas no chrome funciona normalmente. No IE eu preciso dar um F5 na listagem para aparecer o novo registro.
Então eu usei essa função e ele atualiza a página mas nesse processo, é como se ele desse o F5 antes de cadastrar o registro, então ele dá o F5 mas não cadastrou a informação.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-cadastra-atividade", function(){
location.reload(true);});
```

Na imagem abaixo mostra a modal onde eu cadastro a informação e atrás a listagem onde deveria aparecer essa nova informação mas não aparece usando o IE, apenas no chrome
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez seu problema seja como fez para recarregar a informação que não funciona no IE e seja melhor corrigir isso. Como que fez isso tudo?

Comment: _"essa informação não lista automaticamente na listagem no IE"_ - podes explicar melhor o que está a falhar aí? parece-me melhor corrigir isso que inventar outros caminhos..

Comment: Poste a parte do Ajax, se existir, o back-end é PHP ou outra tecnologia? O problema provavelmente é cache. *Por favor* leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, sergio, guilherme, eu estou usando angular, e encontrei uma solução mas ela não funciona no IE, por isso estou tentando forçar no javascript

Comment: @Isa mas seria mais interessante perceber o que falha no IE? podes explicar o que falha?

Comment: @Sergio no IE ele só lista o novo registro depois que eu dou F5 na página. Já no chhrome ele funciona corretamente, assim que eu adiciono um novo registro ele lista sem precisar dar F5, eu acredito que é uma particularidade do IE

Comment: @Isa podes colocar na pergunta o código que gera essa listagem que está a falhar?

Comment: @Isa posta o código de menaira que possamos entender e reproduzir, da maneira que esta vamos ficar no "acho que é isso, acho que é aquilo". Crie um exemplo minimo reproduzível https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Você pode mostrar a função que faz o cadastro ?